# Find the Maximum Trigonometric polynomial coefficient $A_{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, trigonometric-series

> Let $n,k$ be given positive integers and $n\ge k$. Let $A_i, i=1, 2, \cdots, n$ be given real numbers. If for all real numbers $x$ we have $$A_{1}\cos{x}+A_{2}\cos{(2x)}+\cdots+A_{n}\cos{(nx)}\le 1$$
> Find the maximum value of $A_{k}$.

I don't know if this question has been studied

If  $n=2$ it is easy to solve it.

Comment: It is not hard to show that $|A_{k,n}|<2$ and the limit of $A_{n,k}$ for $k$ odd as $n \to \infty$ is $2$ (the absolute value limit is $2$ regardless of parity) while various positive kernels (eg Feijer) give easy inferior limits again at least for $k$ odd as the problem is stated

Comment: Are you assuming sums $s(x) := A_1 \cos x + \cdots + A_n \cos nx$ are available?

Comment: This just screams to use a conveniently defined function $f(x) \leq 1$ and find its Fourier series on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ since you'll get the desired $\cos(kx)$ term by using that interval. If using the Fourier series you will have another constraint - $f(x)$ should be even since you only have cosine terms in the end sum.

Comment: What's the role of $k$? I don't see it

Comment: @enzotib For example, $n=2, k=1$, under the condition $A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, the maximum of $A_1$ is $\sqrt{2}$ (For example, when $A_1 = \sqrt{2}, A_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$, the condition is satisfied.) If $A_1 > \sqrt{2}$, there is not $A_2$ such that $A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @enzotib Another example: $n=2, k=2$, under the condition $A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, the maximum of $A_2$ is $1$ (For example, when $A_1=0, A_2 = 1$, the condition is satisfied.) If $A_2 > 1$, there is not $A_1$ such that $A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos{kx} =\frac { e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx}}{2}$ we can restate the condition in this form
let $$P(x) = 1 - \sum_{k=-n}^{k=n} \frac{A_{k}}{2}*e^{ikx}$$ where $A_{-k} = A_{k}$.
If $P(x) >= 0$ find the upper bound on $A_{k}$.
Now, there is a lemma due to Riesz which says that a real positive polynomial is a square. In words, that there is a trigonometric polynomial $Q(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{k=n}\frac{1}{2\pi}a_{k}e^{ikx}$ such that $P(x) = |Q(x)|^{2} = Q(x)\overline Q(x)$
Multiplying out and comparing coefficients, one gets
$$\sum |a_{k}|^{2} = (2\pi)^{2}$$ and $$\frac{1}{2}A_{k} = (\frac{1}{2\pi})^{2}\sum a_{l}*\overline a_{l + k}$$
Then, if one applies Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to the last expression and uses the previous estimate on sum of squares of $a_{k}$'s one gets:
$$A_{k} <= 2$$
Not the optimal estimation (as the case n=1 shows) but a uniform one with respect to $n$.

Comment: It is a nice approach to get an upper bound for $A_k$. (+1) I check the case $n=2$, $A_1 = \sqrt{2}, A_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$ to understand it. Is it $- \frac{1}{2}A_{k} = (\frac{1}{2\pi})^{2}\sum a_{l}*\overline a_{l + k}$?

Comment: Well ... it does not matter. What matters is that this is a scalar product of a vector with its shift so we can use Cauchy-Schwartz and get estimate $A_{k} <= 2$ since the length of the vector is known. This was the original problem. As far as second problem is concerned, i.e. that $A_{k}$<= 1 for k >= [n/2] one has to be more picky about  $Q$. As I said in other comments it matters now that spectrum of $Q$ is between $-[n/2]$ and $[n/2]$. Still, I think that for even n one can produce counterexample since the formula for "middle" coefficients will have "half" + 1 elements.

Comment: I have proved that $A_n \le 1$ for all $n\ge 2$. Thus, $\max A_n = 1$. See the update of my answer.

Comment: Hmm ... but in other posts you did estimates for n=3 and n= 4 and you got that $A_{1}$ is $\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ respectively.

Comment: $n=2$, $\max A_2 = 1$; $n=3$, $\max A_3 = 1$; $n=4$, $\max A_4 = 1$.

Comment: $n=5$, we have $\max A_1 \approx 1.8019$ (has a complicated closed form), $\max A_2 = \sqrt{2}$, $\max A_3 = \max A_4 = \max A_5 = 1$.

Comment: $n=9$, $\max A_1 \approx 1.9190$, $\max A_2 = \sqrt{3}$, $\max A_3 = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$, $\max A_4 = \sqrt{2}$, $\max A_5 = \max A_6 = \max A_7 = \max A_8 = \max A_9 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**NTstrucker**@AoPS's answer:

It is a known result:
$$\max A_k = 2 \cos \frac{\pi}{\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor + 2}, \ 1\le k \le n.$$
See e.g. Theorem 16.2.4 in [1].

So, $\max A_1 = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{n + 2}$,
$\max A_m = 1$ for $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1 \le m \le n$,
$\max A_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} = \sqrt{2}$.

[1] Qazi Ibadur Rahman and Gerhard Schmeisser, “Analytic Theory of Polynomials”, 2002.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT

May be this idea can help:

We use following identity:

$$\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(2x)+\sin^2 (3x)+ . . .+\sin^2(nx)=\frac{n\sin(x)-\sin(nx)\cos(n+1)x}{2\sin x}$$

Taking derivative of both sides we get:

$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)+4\sin(2x)\cos(2x)+6\sin(3x)\cos(3x)+ . . . 2n\sin(nx)\cos(nx)=\big(\frac{n\sin(x)-\sin(nx)\cos(n+1)x}{2\sin x}\big)'\leq 1$$

We solve derivative $\leq 1$, we get a relation between n and x which may be used to find maximum value of $A_k$.
In fact the proble can be reduced to:
If:

$\big(\frac{n\sin(x)-\sin(nx)\cos(n+1)x}{2\sin x}\big)'\leq 1$

Find maximum of  $A_n=f(x)= 2n\sin(nx)$

Comment: I think that in the question, $A_k$'s are independent of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just do a subcase of the $n=3$ case.

$A_{k}=1$ is the maximum for k=2, 3.

First notice that letting $A_{k}=1$ and taking the other values of $A_{j}=0$ we have

$$cos(kx)\leq 1$$

which holds for all x. So each $A_{k}$ is at least 1. Now we will show that each $A_{k}$ is at most 1 for $k=2,3$.

Plugging in $x=0$ gives us $A_{1}+A_{2}+A_{3} \leq 1$.

If $A_{3}>1$ then this forces $A_{1}+A_{2} \leq 1-A_{3} < 0$. However, plugging in $x=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ we have $A_{3} + \frac{-A_{1}-A_{2}}{2} \leq 1$

So $A_{3}\leq 1+\frac{A_{1}+A_{2}}{2} < 1$

Therefore $A_{3}\leq 1$ thus $A_{3}=1$.

If $A_{2}>1$ then $A_{1}+A_{3} \leq 1-A_{2} < 0$.

Plugging in $x=\pi$ we have $A_{2} + -A_{1}-A_{3} \leq 1$.

So $A_{2}\leq 1+ A_{1} + A_{3} < 1$.

Therefore $A_{2}\leq 1$ thus $A_{2}=1$.

Comment: (+1). It is a nice solution which can be restated as: Letting $x=0$, $x = \frac{2}{3}\pi$ and $x = \pi$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 &\le 1, \tag{1}\\
-\frac{1}{2}A_1 - \frac{1}{2}A_2 + A_3 &\le 1, \tag{2}\\
-A_1 + A_2 - A_3 &\le 1. \tag{3}
\end{align}
$(1) + (3)$ gives $2A_2 \le 2$. $(1) + 2\times (2)$ gives $3A_3 \le 3$.
Thus, $A_2 \le 1$ and $A_3 \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** (2021/02/05)

We need to solve the optimization problem:
\begin{align}
&\max\quad A_m\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\quad \sum_{k=1}^n A_k\cos (kx) \le 1, \ \forall x\in [0, 2\pi], \\
&\qquad\quad A_k \in \mathbb{R}, \forall k.
\end{align}
It can be viewed as a "Linear Programming" with uncountable many linear constraints.
However, as in the special cases ($n=2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ etc. see below), perhaps we can choose a few linear constraints such that $\max A_m$ is the same.
In other words, the following optimization problem has the same maximum as the previous one.
\begin{align}
&\max\quad A_m\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\quad \sum_{k=1}^n A_k\cos (kx_j) \le 1, \ j = 1, 2, \cdots, M, \\
&\qquad\quad A_k \in \mathbb{R}, \forall k.
\end{align}
where $x_j$'s are chosen in advance (see the special cases below).

How to choose a set of $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_M$?

**Conjecture** 1: $\max A_m = 1$ for $m = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1, \cdots, n$.
(**Edit** (2021/02/08): I have proved Conjecture 1 in my another answer.)

$\phantom{2}$

**Some special cases** $n=3, 4$

Remark: I will add more cases if possible.

**Case** $n=3$

1. $\max A_1 = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2} \approx 1.6180$

Letting $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{2\pi}{5}$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 &\le 1, \tag{1}\\
A_1\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} - (A_2 + A_3)\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4} &\le 1. \tag{2}
\end{align}
$(1)\times \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{4} + (2)$ gives $A_1 \le \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.

Also, when $A_1 = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}, A_2 = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, 
A_3 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}$, we have
\begin{align}
&A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x + A_3 \cos 3x - 1\\
=\ & \frac{5 - \sqrt{5}}{40}(1-\cos x)(\sqrt{5} - 1 - 4\cos x)^2 \le 0.
\end{align}
The desired result follows.

2. $\max A_2 = 1$ and $\max A_3 = 1$ (has been solved by @**open problem**)

Letting $x=0$, $x = \frac{2}{3}\pi$ and $x = \pi$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 &\le 1, \tag{3}\\
-\frac{1}{2}A_1 - \frac{1}{2}A_2 + A_3 &\le 1, \tag{4}\\
-A_1 + A_2 - A_3 &\le 1. \tag{5}
\end{align}
$(3) + (5)$ gives $A_2 \le 1$, and $(3) + 2\times (4)$ gives $A_3 \le 1$.

The remaining is easy.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case** $n=4$

1. $\max A_1 = \sqrt{3}$

Letting $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} A_1 + \frac{1}{2}A_2 - \frac{1}{2}A_4 &\le 1, \tag{6}\\
-A_2 + A_4 &\le 1.\tag{7}
\end{align}
$(6)\times 2 + (7)$ gives $A_1 \le \sqrt{3}$.

Also, when $A_1 = \sqrt{3}, A_2 = - \frac{7}{6},
A_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, A_4 = - \frac{1}{6}$, we have
\begin{align}
&A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x + A_3 \cos 3x + A_4\cos 4x - 1\\
=\ & -\frac{\cos^2 x}{3} (\sqrt{3} - 2\cos x)^2\\
\le\ & 0.
\end{align}
The desired result follows.

2. $\max A_2 = \sqrt{2}$

Letting $x = \frac{\pi}{8}$ and $x = \frac{7\pi}{8}$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
A_1 \cos \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{A_2}{\sqrt{2}} + A_3\cos \frac{3\pi}{8} &\le 1, \tag{8} \\
-A_1 \cos \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{A_2}{\sqrt{2}} - A_3\cos \frac{3\pi}{8} &\le 1. \tag{9}
\end{align}
$(8) + (9)$ gives $A_2\le \sqrt{2}$.

Also, when $A_1 = 0, A_2 = \sqrt{2}, A_3 = 0, A_4 = -\frac{1}{2}$, we have
\begin{align}
&A_1\cos x + A_2\cos 2x + A_3 \cos 3x + A_4\cos 4x - 1\\
=\ & -\frac{1}{4} (2 + \sqrt{2} - 4\cos^2 x)^2\\
\le\ & 0.
\end{align}
The desired result follows.

3. $\max A_3 = 1$ and $\max A_4 = 1$

Letting $x = 0$, $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $x=\pi$ respectively, we have
\begin{align}
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4 &\le 1, \tag{10}\\
-A_2 + A_4 &\le 1, \tag{11}\\
-\frac{1}{2}A_1 - \frac{1}{2}A_2 + A_3 - \frac{1}{2}A_4 &\le 1, \tag{12}\\
-A_1 + A_2 - A_3 + A_4 &\le 1. \tag{13}
\end{align}
$(10) + (12)\times 2$ gives $A_3 \le 1$, and $(10) + (11)\times 2 + (13)$ gives $A_4 \le 1$. The remaining is easy.

Comment: The conjecture that $A_{k} <= 1$ for $k>[\frac{n}{2}] + 1$ is not true based on solution I provided above. Just take $a_{k} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt2n}$ for each $k$ and you get $A_{\frac{n}{2}}$ about $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @Salcio Thanks for comment. Do you check if $A_1\cos x + A_2 \cos 2x + \cdots + A_n\cos nx \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ holds?

Comment: sure, read my post above please. This is trigonometric polynomial so it is periodic. The whole problem (via Riesz's lemma) reduces basically to estimation of "shifted" scalar product of a vector with given length,

Comment: @Salcio Can you give me an example for $n=2$?

Comment: please look at the post. Possibly I am rounding some estimates and the constants are good for $n$ "sufficiently" large.

Comment: @Salcio Do you mean my conjecture is not true for sufficiently large $n$? For small $n$, my conjecture is true.

Comment: I am saying much more. Namely, that my post shows how to generate such "cosine" polynomials and what are formulas for $A_{k}$. In words, that asking about maximum of $A_{k}$ (given bound on "cosine" polynomial) is the same as asking for maximum of "shifted" scalar product of a vector with given length.

Comment: Well, the post states that $\frac{1}{2}A_{k} = (\frac{1}{2\pi})^{2}\sum a_{l}*\overline a_{l + k}$ subject to condition  on the length of vector $a_{k}$. Just read the post and you will be fine.

Comment: No ... you are confusing $a_{k}$ with $A_{k}$. Please read the post! If you refuse to read the post then the whole discussion does not make much sense.

Comment: @Salcio Sorry, I made a mistake. I misunderstood $a_k$ and $A_k$. I will check it again.

Comment: @Salcio I don't understand your post. Can you just tell me: my conjecture is true for small $n$, for example, $n=2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12$ (I did it), right? And you said my conjecture is not true for sufficiently large $n$, right?

Comment: @Salcio I am very sorry. I just think you will give me $A_k$ directly to disprove my conjecture.

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct myself. My post is fine in the sense that $A_{k} <= 2$ always. But the spectrum of $Q$ is not from -n to n but from $[n/2]$ to $[n/2]$ (roughly speaking, this makes sense for even $n$ at least. Accordingly, we get $\frac{1}{2}A_{k} = (\frac{1}{2\pi})^{2}\sum a_{l}*\overline a_{l + k}$ and since the sum is taken from $-[n/2]$ to $[n/2]$ it comes as close to $1$ if all $a_{k}$ are identical. So, identical $a_{k}$ may not produce counterexample, one has to shift them a little.

Comment: About giving a concrete example. Please note that the formula for $A_{k}$ involves sum of elements which are ration of $\pi$ and some roots of $n$. I am too old to compute such things, I used to be able to do this when I was younger :). Just make the effort to understand the post and you will agree with me that it gives formula for all such "cosine" polynomials.

Comment: @Salcio Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

My second answer:

**Edit** 2021/03/11

According to NTstrucker@AoPS's result (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2477208), I give the following conjecture.

**Conjecture 2**: $\max A_1 = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{n+2}$.

When $n = 2$, $\max A_1 = \sqrt{2} = 2 \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$.

When $n = 3$, $\max A_1 = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2} = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{5}$.

When $n = 4$, $\max A_1 = \sqrt{3} = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{6}$.

When $n = 5$, $\max A_1 = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{7}$.

When $n = 6$, $\max A_1 \approx 1.8478$ (I only get numerical result) should be $2\cos \frac{\pi}{8}
\approx 1.847759065$.

When $n = 7$, $\max A_1 \approx 1.8794$ (I only get numerical result) should be $2\cos \frac{\pi}{9}
\approx 1.879385242$.

When $n = 8$, $\max A_1 \approx 1.9021$ (I only get numerical result) should be $2\cos \frac{\pi}{10}
\approx 1.902113033$.

When $n = 9$, $\max A_1 \approx 1.9190$ (I only get numerical result) should be $2\cos \frac{\pi}{11}
\approx 1.918985947$.

$\phantom{2}$

Let us prove that $\max A_m = 1$ if $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1 \le m \le n$.

We need Theorem 1. The proof is given at the end.

**Theorem 1**: Let $n\ge 2$ be a given integer. Let $A_i, i=1, 2, \cdots, n$ be given real numbers such
that $A_1\cos x + A_2 \cos 2x + \cdots + A_n \cos n x \le 1, \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$A_m \le 1$ for $m = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1,  \cdots, n$.

By Theorem 1, we have immediately $\max A_m = 1$ if $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1 \le m \le n$
(simply let $A_m = 1$ and $A_k = 0$ for all $k\ne m$
and the condition $A_m \cos m x \le 1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ is clearly satisfied.).

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Theorem 1*: First, we have Fact 1. The proof of Fact 1 is easy and thus omitted.

*Fact 1*: Let $M\ge 2$ be an integer. Let $K$ be a positive integer. Then
$$\frac{1}{M} + \frac{\cos K\pi}{M}\cdot \frac{1 + (-1)^M}{2}
+ \frac{2}{M}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{M+1}{2}\rfloor - 1} \cos \frac{2jK\pi}{M} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                                                              0 & M \nmid K \\[5pt]
                                                              1 & M \mid K.
                                                            \end{array}
\right.$$

Second, we have Fact 2.

*Fact 2*: Let $n\ge 2$ be a given integer. Let $m$ be an integer with $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1 \le m \le n$.
Let $A_i, i= 1, 2, \cdots, n$ be given real numbers.
Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k\cos (kx)$. Then
$$\frac{f(0)}{m} + \frac{f(\pi)}{m}\cdot \frac{1 + (-1)^m}{2}
+ \frac{2}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor - 1} f\left(\frac{2j\pi}{m}\right) = A_m. $$
(*Proof of Fact 2*: It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{m} + \frac{\cos k\pi}{m}\cdot \frac{1 + (-1)^m}{2}
+ \frac{2}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{m+1}{2}\rfloor - 1} \cos \frac{2j k \pi}{m} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                                                              0 & k \ne m \\[5pt]
                                                              1 & k = m.
                                                            \end{array}
\right. $$
This is true by Fact 1.)

By Fact 2, Theorem 1 is proved. We are done.

Comment: ,你好,我看了你的一些帖子,发现你好像来自中国.非常高兴认识你

Comment: @inequality Nice to meet you. Your question is interesting.